# Why are these low-variance principal components correlated among subjects?

Tags: pca, modeling

I'm analyzing some body tracking data. Beginning with velocity data from each upper-body joint, PCA is run on about 15 minutes (~1000s of frames) of this tracking data for 24 participants. Out, we get 13 different PCs (as there are 13 joints tracked by Kinect) for 24 participants. As one would expect, the first two or three principal components are correlated among participants. They essentially describe rigid body motion (if I sway side-to-side with talking, the positions of all my joints move) and arm motion (next often, I move my hands while my body stays still).

However, I'd expect the PCs that have very low variance would be mostly noise, but they are HIGHLY correlated among all participants. Is there a statistical reason this would happen, or is this likely due to the fact that joints move similarly across people?

Comment: I think that without access to you data, it is very hard to answer this decisively... What exactly do you mean by "*they are HIGHLY correlated among all participants*"? The PCs are/should be orthogonal with each other; this does not necessitate uncorrelatedness but it does make it quite hard to observe high correlations.

Comment: PCA is run separately on each participant's joint motion. If I take PC1 from Participant 1's data, and correlate it with PC1 of Participant 2's data, I get a high (0.9) correlation. That's reasonable. I was surprised that the low-variance principal components were also correlated between participants, because I expected those to be noise.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what PCA does - the low-variance components can also be understood as the vectors along which there is the least variance, that is just as likely to be consistent across the participants as the highest-variance component.

Comment: I think that this is a sensible interpretation, yes.

Comment: You should really add new information in comments as an edit to the post, and, if you now solved, you can self-answer!